# Prove $3/4 \leq \sin^2 x + \cos ^4 x \leq 1$ for all real $x$:

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$A= \sin^2 x + \cos ^4 x$$ then for all real $x$: prove that:
>    $$3/4 \le A \le 1.$$
>   I am not able to get the value or set up the required formula. I am also not able to understand the question well.

My solution. Can't proceed further:

$$\begin{align} A&=\sin^2{x}+\cos^4{x} \\ &=(\sin{x}+\cos^2{x})^2-2\sin{x}\cos^2{x}\\&=1-\cos^2{x}+\cos^4{x}\\&=1-\cos^2{x}(1+\cos^2{x}) \end{align}$$

Comment: In the last hour you have posted four questions on elementary trigonometry, none of which show any significant effort.  This is not a homework site.

Comment: I have solved all the problems I am just clarifying my doubts.

Comment: Good.  Please edit your post to show your solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note: $$\sin^2x+\cos^4x=\sin^2x+(1-\sin^2x)^2=\sin^4x-\sin^2x+1=$$
$$\sin^2x(\sin^2x-1)+1=1-\frac14\sin^22x.$$

Then:
$$\frac34\le1-\frac14\sin^22x\le1 \Rightarrow 0\le \sin^22x\le 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

No sophisticated trigonometry formula required, but Pythagoras' relation and a knowledge of quadratic functions:
$$\sin^2x+\cos^4x=\sin^2x+(1-=\sin^2x)^2=\sin^4x-\sin^2x+1.$$
Now set $t=\sin^2x$ $\;(0\le t\le1)$. You get the quadratic polynomial $p(t)=t^2-t+1$, which has a *minimum* for $t=-\frac b{2a}=\frac 12$, and this minimum is equal to $p(\frac12)=\frac34$.

Furthermore $p(t)$ is decreasing on $\bigl[0,\frac12\bigr]$,  increasing on $\bigl[\frac12,1\bigr]$ and $p(0)=p(1)=1$, whence the inequalities.